# A question about wifi 13.04

Tags: wireless, 13.04

I have a toshiba satellite computer... I have ubuntu 13.04 installed and my wifi is lower than what it is when I had windows 8.  I was wondering if there was some way that I could fix it so I could have a better connection... any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: do you mean that the signal strength appears lower, or that the connection itself is slower?

Answer (score 0):

Some things to consider.

The connection could "appear" to be worse due to the way the icon displays your connection. You might want to check your actual ping response times and your connection rate to see if it is in fact worse. Open a terminal and issue command

```
iwconfig
```

and look for bitrate, and command

```
ping -c 4 192.168.1.1
```

(or whatever your router IP address is) and check your response times (you will probably want something in the neighborhood of 5ms or less over wireless). Is it running slowly for you?

If it is, Ubuntu may be using a generic driver where there is a better driver provided by the wireless chip manufacturer. That is something you might want to determine from the system specs of your particular model computer.

More information concerning your PC's model name/number and your actual connection rates might help pin down a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with one of my friend's toshiba satallite with Atheros wireless device.Some wifi drivers for ubuntu 13.04 manages a power management scheme. This power management helps increasing battary life by limiting power for the wifi adapter by reducing the performance of your adapter. When you run

```
iwconfig
```

you might see a line in the output saying

```
Power Mangement: On
```

If it says so, that is your problem. You can solve it running the following command.

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

*replace 'wlan0' with your interface name

To make this permanent, you can include this command as a shell script in the folder

`/etc/pm/power.d`

To do this follow given steps,

```
cd /etc/pm/power.d
sudo nano wifi_pwm
```

In the editor, include followings in the newly created file.

```
#!/bin/sh 
/sbin/iwconfig/ wlan0 power off
```

Save your file with Ctrl + O and exit with Ctrl + X.

Reboot your machine, then you will turn off power management permanently.

Comment: Since the sequence above is now persistent, I will delete my comment above.